# sources.list file missing

Tags: linux, debian

to edit `sources.list`, on doing from root user,

```
 nano etc/apt/sources.list
```

nano text editor appears as a new file and on saving, it throws an error:-

> etc/apt/sources.list : no such file exist**

How to edit this to update debian? (`apt-get update` not working).

Comment: may be relative path problem try `nano /etc/apt/sources.list`

Comment: that was my first thought too, but he said "apt-get update not working"

Answer (score 2):

you are missing `/` in the beginning

**`nano /etc/apt/sources.list`**

Comment: It took me to the file but the file but the file was empty! Howto cover it up??

Comment: @anmolsharma cas posted an anwer for that, just fill it with the defaults for now, I suggest

Answer (score 0):

Here's the default debian sources.list for jessie with the deb-src lines commented out (uncomment them if you ever intend to download source packages).

```
deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian jessie main
#deb-src http://httpredir.debian.org/debian jessie main

deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian jessie-updates main
#deb-src http://httpredir.debian.org/debian jessie-updates main

deb http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main
#deb-src http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main
```

Useful aliases to turn the deb-src lines on and off are:

```
alias apt-source-on='sed -i -e "s/^#\(deb-src\)/\1/" /etc/apt/sources.list'
alias apt-source-off='sed -i -e "s/^\(deb-src\)/#\1/" /etc/apt/sources.list'
```

Change 'jessie' to the appropriate release nickname if you are using a different release.  For example:

```
sed -i -e '/^#*deb/ s/jessie/stretch/g' /etc/apt/sources.list
```

If you want `contrib` or `non-free` packages add either `contrib` or `non-free` or both to the end of each line.  For example, with:

```
sed -i -e '/^#*deb/ s/$/ contrib non-free/' /etc/apt/sources.list
```

If you have a local mirror that you prefer to use, change it with:

```
sed -i -e 's/httpredir.debian.org/your.mirror.example.com/g' /etc/apt/sources.list
```

For more information on sources.list, see https://wiki.debian.org/SourcesList