# sources.list file empty in debian

Tags: debian, apt, etc

[image]On running 
**nano /etc/apt/sources.list** , 
the text editor opens the *sources.list* file but it is completely empty! How to get the default *sources.list* file as I am unable to update debian (*apt-get update*).

Comment: you asked the exact same question yesterday. http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/239696/sources-list-file-missing/239698#239698

Comment: Not exactly but i was unable to open that file only yesterday due to a missing / before etc. But after that, i encountered this.Co-incidently they look same. But now, after searching in other places ,i got the content of sources.list and after typing those in sources.list, it is not able to connect to ftp.us.debian.org/debian after showing 67% As there is no primary mirror for India, what to do next?

Comment: You should have accepted the answer from @burian.vlastimil in that question. Just saying .....

Answer (score 5):

Are you sure the file is empty? Do you get a file size of 0 with this command?

```
ls -la /etc/apt/sources.list
```

There should be a copy (of your distribution) in here:

```
 /usr/share/doc/apt/examples/sources.list
```

And, Assuming you are using jessie distribution, you could write this one line to sources.list, to start working:

```
deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ jessie main contrib non-free
```

Then just do `apt-get update` to get a basic list of packages. After that, be very careful of what you install until you get your sources sorted.

You better use Synaptic to reinstall apt. If not available, do:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall apt
```

Be careful!!

Comment: on writing only one line in sources.list i.e. deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ jessie main contrib non-free it's working till 67% but not able to complete a process that connects to ftp.us.debian.org ,I am from India and there is no primary mirror for this country.

Comment: Is this file `/usr/share/doc/apt/examples/sources.list` also missing????

Comment: this file exist but holds the US mirror. So I edited that too to debianmirror.nkn.in (indian leaf mirror). but still same issue exist!

Comment: You do not edit that file. You should copy it to `sources.list`, then edit it. If you still have an issue, there is something else broken.

Comment: This answer saved me. I thought I messed up my dad's laptop. Thanks a ton :)